# Vertically ordered matrix to horizontal order

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

Sorry for the vague title, I am not sure how to call it.

I am looking for a generic transformation that transforms a vertically ordered array to a horizontally ordered one. The array always has 4 columns, with arbitrary number of rows.

This is motivated by the fact that I have a (potentially uneven) grid where the entries are ordered by date column by column, that is

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 5 & 9 & 12\\\\
2 & 6 & 10 & 13\\\\
3 & 7 & 11 & 14\\\\\
4 & 8 &  & 
\end{matrix}
$$

I want to transform it to a horizontally ordered grid, with the same shape:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\\\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\\\\
13 & 14 &  & 
\end{matrix}
$$

This can be thought of as a permutation
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14\\\\
1 & 5 & 9 & 13&2&6&10&14&3&7&11&4&8&12
\end{pmatrix}
$$
**Is there a way to write down an explicit formula?**

If I try to state the problem more generally, consider a $N\times 4$ matrix $a_{ij}\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a_{ij}\geq 0$, $a_{11} = 1$. First condition is that **all non-zero entries** are distinct and $a_{ij}\leq N$ for all $i,j$.

$a_{ij}$ can, for example, be always positive, but we allow zero values only in the bottom row, and the bottom row mustn't be all zeros (or else we will take a $(N-1)\times 4$ matrix). That is we have the condition
$$
a_{ij} = 0\Rightarrow i=N, j>1
$$
For the horizontal order, we simply impose:
$$
\forall j,i\ {\rm s.t.}\ a_{i+1,j}\neq 0,\ \ \ a_{i+1,j} = 1+a_{i,j}
$$
The difference between columns is tricky,
$$
\forall i,j,\ a_{i,j+1}\neq0\ \ \begin{cases}
a_{N,j} = 0, a_{N,j-1}\neq0&\Rightarrow a_{i,j+1} = 4+a_{ij} \\\\
a_{N,j} = 0, a_{N,j-1} = 0& \Rightarrow a_{i,j+1} = 3+a_{ij} \\\\
a_{N,j} \neq 0& \Rightarrow a_{i,j+1} = 4+a_{ij}
\end{cases}
$$

I want to find a transformation $T$, such that $Ta_{ij} = b_{ij}$, where $b_{ij}$ is a $N\times 4$ matrix $b_{i,j}\in\mathbb{Z}$,$b_{ij}\geq0$, $b_{11}=1$ such that
$$
a_{ij} = 0 \Rightarrow b_{ij} = 0
$$
$$
\forall j,i\ {\rm s.t.}\ b_{i+1,j}\neq 0,\ \ \ b_{i+1,j} = 1+b_{i,j}
$$
For the new matrix, it seems that the difference between rows with non-zero entries is always 4:
$$
\forall j,i\ {\rm s.t.}\ b_{i,j+1}\neq 0,\ \ \ b_{i,j+1} = 4+b_{i,j}
$$

I think I covered everything in an attempt to state the problem more formally, however this generalization is very messy. I hope the example above makes the goal clearer.

Comment: Since every finite matrix is a representation of a linear transformation of a vector space, is this actually a matrix at all?  What are empty spaces in a matrix?  Normal convention doesn't allow this, yet here we're using empty space in a way that's critical to the design of the mapping.

Comment: @PhillipHamilton We could always call it a "tableau" instead